# kendoUI angular- how to make cell hyperlink

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular-routerlink

I am using kendo UI grid in angular 6 application. In the kendo-grid-column, I want to be able to click EmployeeId and direct user to another component to show details. I am trying to use [routerLink] in anchor tag, but it is not acting as a clickable hyperlink. Also please check if my syntax is correct.

```
<kendo-grid [data]="view | async"
        [pageSize]="state.take"
        [skip]="state.skip"
        [sort]="state.sort"
        [filter]="state.filter"
        [sortable]="true"
        [pageable]="true"
        [filterable]="true"
        [height]="500"
        (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)">
<kendo-grid-checkbox-column title="Select" width="75" showSelectAll="true"></kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="EmployeeID" title="Employee ID" width="220">
    <a [routerLink]="['/contList']" [queryParams]="{'EmployeeID': {{EmployeeID}}}">
    </a>
</kendo-grid-column>
<kendo-grid-column field="EmployeeName" title="Employee Name" width="220">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: try to put your a element in ng-template : <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem >
                   <a [routerLink]="['/contList']" [queryParams]="{'EmployeeID': {{EmployeeID}}}">
    </a>
                </ng-template>

Comment: and dont use interpolation in queryParams, change it to : [queryParams]="{'EmployeeID': EmployeeID}"

Comment: by using  [queryParams]="{'EmployeeID': EmployeeID}" , EmployeeID is not displaying on the grid. rest of the cols are displaying. I dont see any errors in dev tools